# Validating Bootstrap radio buttons on mouseup/keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit complex form (includes inputs, textareas, custom selects, etc). I want to perform validation (just to check whether all fields are empty or not). Nothing more.

But I find it difficult to validate whether a radio button was selected or not. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have styled the radio buttons through their javascript and css (`btn-group`).

I want whenever a user types or clicks something to run the script which checks whether the field is empty or not.

I will post a jsFiddle link below which reproduces my problem. The javascript I use is a bit different, because I want to perform the check only to inputs in the current tab.

```
$('body').on('keyup mouseup ', 'li, label, input, textarea, select', function (e) {
    var tabId = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
    var inputs = $('#' + tabId + ' :input');
    var errors = {};
    inputs.each(function (i, element) {
        if ($(element).attr('name') !== undefined) {
            if ($(element).attr('type') !== 'radio') {
                if ($.trim($(element).val()) === '') {
                    errors[i] = $(element).attr('name');
                }
            } else {
                if ($('.active', $("input[name='" + $(element).attr('name') + "']").closest('.btn-group')).length <= 0) {
                    errors[i] = $(element).attr('name');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(errors);
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(errors)) {
        $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"]')
            .html("<i class='red ace-icon fa fa-times bigger-120'></i> " + $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').text());
    } else {
        $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"]')
            .html("<i class='green ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120'></i> " + $('a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').text());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzwyddrc/
To reproduce the problem:

1. Click on the text field (An alert will tell you that the form is not valid) - **OK**
2. Close the alert and type one letter (otherwise you will be annoyed by the alert). The alert will pop out again telling you that the form is still invalid. - **OK**
3. Now click on one of the radio buttons. The alert will still tell you that the form is invalid. - **NOT OK**
4. If you click on either the text field or one of the radio buttons the alert has something else to say: THE FORM IS VALID! - **NOT OK**

I believe I've misused the events that I binded to the elements I want to fire that validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've looked into this, but there were quite a lot of changes I had to make.

This is the code:

```
$("form").on("keyup mouseup", function (ev) {
    var selected, errors = [];

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("input,select").each(function (i, v) {
            var e;

            e = $(v);
            if (e.attr("name") === undefined) return;

            switch (e.attr("type"))
            {
                case "radio":
                    selected = false;
                    e.closest(".btn-group").find("input[type=radio]").each(function (i, v) {
                        if ($(v).closest("label").hasClass("active"))
                        {
                            selected = true;
                        }
                    });

                    if (!selected) {
                        errors.push(e.attr("id"));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if ($.trim(e.val()) === "")
                    {
                        errors.push(e.attr("name")); // should be id?
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            alert("ERRORS: " + errors);
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

The changes I made are:

- event handlers are attached to the `form`, this is more convenient especially for multi-form pages (imagine a separate `form` on the top for login);
- the selector also considers `select` (dropdowns) a possible input field;
- minor name/order changes to make it more readable;
- the `switch` replaces the `if`, because you will encounter more input types further along (`switch` scales better than `if..else`);
- replaced the error object with an error array on which to `push()` errors;
- when a radio group is unselected, the whole group is invalid, not any single one of the radio buttons nested, so the check should be based on the group as a whole (see use of `selected` flag);
- for radio buttons the `active` class is toggled on the `label` not on the `input`;
- finally, the most important feature you'll already have noticed:

> Bootstrap itself uses events and JS to toggle the `active` class, so if you check it right away the `label` will never have the `active` class -- to counter this, I inserted a `setTimeout()` that will fire validation 10 ms later (which still is instantly for humans) so that Bootstrap has all the time to make an update pass over the form **before** we go in and validate.

I checked it thoroughly in a fiddle, so I'm quite confident it works well and opens up many possibilities you've probably envisioned.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really flexible and well thought.

Comment: I just realized that `textarea` is also an input field!

Comment: Yep, no problems. I added that :)